# javascript XMLHttpRequest кросс-доменный запрос

Tags: javascript, soap, xmlhttprequest, cors

Добрый день!

Столкнулся с такой проблемой apache при попытке отправки soap запроса с помощью js возвращает статус 401.

Код на js(возвращает 401)

```
   function soap() {
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();        
    xmlhttp.open('POST', 'http://url.1cws', true);
    xmlhttp.withCredentials = 1;//с это строкой и без нее результат одинаковый
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Basic ' + btoa("user:pass"));

    var sr = '
    <v:Envelope xmlns:i="http://localhost/rt2" 
    xmlns:d="http://localhost/rt2" xmlns:c="http://localhost/rt2"
    xmlns:v="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <v:Header />
    <v:Body>
    <GetShopCategoriesList 
     xmlns="http://localhost/rt2" id="o0" c:root="1" />
    </v:Body>
    </v:Envelope>';

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
     if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4) {
       if (xmlhttp.status == 200) {
        alert(xmlhttp.resposeText);
         }
        }
      }     
    xmlhttp.send(sr);

 }
```

Хотя если сделать аналогичный запрос на php с помощью curl все нормально, ответ приходит как надо

Код на php(работает)

```
$username='user';
$password='pass';
$URL='http://url.1cws';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$URL);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$username:$password");  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, '
<v:Envelope xmlns:i="http://localhost/rt2" 
xmlns:d="http://localhost/rt2" xmlns:c="http://localhost/rt2"
xmlns:v="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<v:Header />
<v:Body>
<GetShopCategoriesList 
 xmlns="http://localhost/rt2" id="o0" c:root="1" />
</v:Body>
</v:Envelope>');

$data = curl_exec($ch);    
curl_close($ch);
echo($data);
```

Конфиг apache

```
  Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
  Header always set Access-Control-Max-Age "10000"
  Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Origin, Authorization, Accept, Client-Security-Token, Accept-Encoding"
  Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT"
```

Через Fiddler получил следующий результат, если открыть ссылку через браузер и авторизоваться введя логин и пароль, то заголовок запроса выглядит так

```
GET /url.1cws?WSDL HTTP/1.1
Host: myhost:81
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:56.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/56.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: ru-RU,ru;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
DNT: 1
Authorization: Basic Zjox
Connection: keep-alive
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
Cache-Control: max-age=0
```

Если выполнять запрос через XMLHttpRequest то так

```
OPTIONS /url.1cws HTTP/1.1
Host: myhost:81
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:56.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/56.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: ru-RU,ru;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Access-Control-Request-Method: POST
Access-Control-Request-Headers: authorization
Origin: http://mysite.ru
Connection: keep-alive
```

Comment: 401 - требуется аутентификация

Comment: курлу пофиг на CORS, кстати

Comment: Fiddler поможет сравнить запросы и найти разницу

Comment: @koshkashoshka в вопрос добавил результаты Fiddler, как я понял при попытке отправки XMLHttpRequest authorization не устанавливается